# Lottie Animation Not Appearing iOS

Tags: ios, swift, animation, lottie

I updated to the latest version (3.0) of `Lottie` and noticed various changes that forced me to alter my code.

Previously, I wanted to be able position animations via `storyboard`, and to do so, I used a `LOTAnimatedControl` and then in code accessed the `animationView` of the control to set the animation via `LOTAnimatedControl.animationView.setAnimation(named: "x")`.

Now it appears this is not possible at all.

What I thought I could do then is..
1. Set a `uiview` outlet in storyboard.
2. Subview an `AnimationView` initialized in code.
3. Setting the animation via `AnimationView.animation = Animation.named("name")`

I set it all up, but I cannot see the animation when I run it. In debugging I see that `Animation.named("x")` prints out to nil, but not sure why. I removed the .json extension in the name and the .json file is exactly where it was before when it was working.

Any ideas would be welcomed. Below is my setup.

```
@IBOutlet weak var activityIndicatorView: UIView!

let activityIndicator = AnimationView()

activityIndicatorView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        activityIndicator.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: activityIndicatorView.centerXAnchor),
        activityIndicator.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: activityIndicatorView.centerYAnchor),
        activityIndicator.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: activityIndicatorView.frame.width),
        activityIndicator.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: activityIndicatorView.frame.height)
        ])
let animation = Animation.named("name")
    activityIndicator.animation = animation
    activityIndicator.isHidden = false
    activityIndicator.loopMode = .loop
    activityIndicator.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

to correctly add programmatic constraints

Answer (score 1):

Still not sure why I was getting nil as I followed the quickstart lottie ios documentation, but my workaround was on initialization of `AnimationView`, I would just bundle it together with the actual animation on initialization - `AnimationView(name: "name")`.